HTML is rendered in Angular before binding to an observable. Lifecycle issue
I have a component that renders a grid of images bound to an Observable<Image[]> named sorted$.
<ng-container *ngFor="let image of sorted$ | async; index as i">
    <img src="..."/>
</ng-container>

I also have a dropdown that can be used to sort the images. I'm using fromEvent() to create an Observable<InputEvent> from the dropdown's select event called sort$.
this.sort$ = fromEvent<InputEvent>(this.sort.nativeElement, "input");

Finally, I have another Observable<Image[]> named source$ that provides all the images that will sorted:
source$!: Observable<Image[]>;

The idea is to sort the images in response to the user choosing a sort option.
this.sorted$ = combineLatest({ source: this.source$, sort: this.sort$ })
   .pipe(map(images => { *** sort logic here ***}));

And, it works! Except for one thing...
When the page is first displayed, no images are rendered because sorted$ hasn't emitted any values - because the user hasn't selected a sort option. When a user does choose an option, everything works - just not on the initial render.
sort$ and sorted$ are created in ngAfterViewInit() because the <select> element isn't yet bound until that point. However, the page has already been rendered.
If I initially assign the sorted$ observable to the value of the source$ observable in the ngOnInit() function, the page will render the images, but when it is later assigned a new value in ngAfterViewInit(), I get the error:
Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

I have chickens and eggs. How can I render the sorted images before I have access to the <select> element?

This error occurs in the development environment. To accomplish the task, I recommend using *ngIf="sorted$ | async as images" in a container to wrap your HTML and then iterate over the images. Does that make sense?

So, nest one container within the other. The outside one checks if any images are available and the inner one does the iteration. The inner container won't attempt to iterate any images until the observable emits them?

You can use startWith rxjs operator
this.sort$ = fromEvent<InputEvent>(this.sort.nativeElement, "input")
                  .pipe(startWith(null));

Or you can use merge instead of combineLastest (that "dispatch" when any observable change)
this.sorted$ = merge(this.source$, this.sort$ }).pipe((res:Image[] | string)=>{
   ..res can be the response to this.source$ or to this.sort$..
})


Thank you! I didn’t know about startsWith - I’ve been using BehaviorSubjects everywhere. That really simplifies things.
